# How can I determine distance of an object over a surface from two images?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, photogrammetry

I have a picture of an object over a surface.  The object is not affixed to anything.  I know the dimensions of the ball.  If needed, I can have multiple pictures of the same scene from different angles.

I've looked around and found a few things, but they haven't been quite what I needed (or maybe I just can't figure out how to apply it to my specific problem).  For example, [Criminisi's paper Single View Metrology](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ph/869/papers/Criminisi99.pdf) can determine the height of an object but (unless I'm misreading it) requires that the object be on the ground.

In other words, in a pictures like [this](http://thumb7.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/61078/61078,1230962644,1/stock-photo-athletic-male-in-the-air-kicking-a-soccer-ball-22690021.jpg), is it possible to determine how far above the ground the ball is?

Comment: If your terrain is horizontal and the camera axis too, then yes. The apparent balloon area gives you the viewing distance and from the distance and the position in the image you can deduce the height. Details of the computation are not trivial, though.

Comment: Thank you!  Could you point me towards some reading material to get me started with the calculation?  And how about cases such as in the picture where the terrain and camera axis aren't horizontal?  Would having multiple images of the scene help?

Comment: You will find a very partial answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1367710/65203 (unfortunately, this solves the direct problem, sphere => ellipse, and not the converse. Several images will indeed help, in particular as regards accuracy. You will resort to stereoscopy then.

Comment: if the ground is the lowest bound of the image, you can simply use hough transform to find the circle in the image (the ball) and the height is the image height minus the circle's y val plus the circle height wich can be detected easly

Comment: @Dr.Haimovitz: not at all. There is perspective. You didn't look at the picture, did you ?